# Anyone Please Help. Listview on flutter not updating

Tags: flutter, listview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yq5w.png
when I click 1st time on Shirshak  it doesnot open anything. When I try to click on mobile 2nd time on Shirshak  it opens new Screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fVMN.png. And when I click 3rd time on mobile in 2 then It opens Shirshak again. But when I click it 4th time then it opens 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqEqv.png . This happens again and again I have to hit same two times to get inside chat screen in flutter.

Here is my code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGYfZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdY1G.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIUKh.png

Comment: Please help anyone
my listview becomes updated only after I navigate to the nextpage for second time. I want to navigate it on the first time

Answer (score 1):

- The function getDataForChat() in line 97 is an asynchronous method but you didn't use await and ansync keyword for it ( many other method which collect data from the internet in your code isn't marked with async and await too).
- You should disabled all the other button when anyone of them is clicked .
- You are using a Stateful Widget, so to change the value of any variable, you must use setState . For example, in line 101, you should use setState to set isLoading to false.

Comment: 1) getDataForchat is called declared on line number 30 and it is async method and I have used it over there. 
3) No its not necessary because it is inside ontap functionality so, even setstate is not added it works. ontap itself adds setState functionality bro.

Comment: Anyways thank you so much for your efforts. I think its because i added the getDataforchat method inside ontap so it gathers information when it is tapped. but because after it is tapped the navigator pushes to the next page using before informationand current data is saved. when tapped another time. It takes current data and navigates to next page using that data and collects data that is just now fed. And it circulates again and again

Comment: In the declaration of `getDataForChat()` method, you shouldn't use void, instead you need to use Future<void> so the app won't behave wrongly. Then, in the call of the getDataforChat in the onTap call back, you need to use await before it. The callback look like : `await getDataForChat(index) ;`

Comment: Wow I'm amazed... It finally worked. Thank you so muchhhhhh. Love you bro. You have finally solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. Can you help me by marking my answer as the right answer and upvote it, I will really preciate it. I need some reputation to show around in my interview !

Comment: Ikr. I tried to do it in a first place but I need 15 reputations to cast a vote but my vote has been recorded. As soon as I reach 15 reputation. My votes will be marked